# "Low disk space" messages despite ample virtual space

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, virtualbox, disk-usage, storage

I am having some storage issues with Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox. I had initially allocated 10GB for the VDI, but have since increased this virtual size to 60GB:

[60GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpEeM.png)

However I frequently get "low disk space" messages and my machine is extremely slow and laggy when running applications:

[low_disk_space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayVBH.png)

I have tried resizing using GParted but am unable to do this for some reason:

[GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOImU.png)

I have included below some screenshots of Disk Usage Analyzer and the df command which I feel might be relevant to this issue. I have run all clean/remove commands but the problem persists. I have also tried to follow answers posted in similar questions without any luck. I would really appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

[disk_usage_analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdIQD.png)

[disk_free](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NMZ4.png)

Comment: There is no 60GB anywhere, only 10GB of space is available.

Comment: What command did you use to grow your VDI with?

Comment: @Terrance I used this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=311&v=7Aqx-VHv2_k&feature=emb_title) with the command vboxmanage.exe modifymedium "[YourPathToVdiFileOfYourVirtualMachine]" --resize [NUMBER]. Thanks for your help

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks for your comment, but could you please expand on what you mean? I'm still unsure of how to solve this since the .vdi says there is approx 60GB allocated to it. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Unless you tell the filesystem to expand, the guest cannot see the extra space you made available. Just because you add extra space does not mean that the filesystem will automatically resize itself to fill up the available space.

It might be worth using `df` to see what volume is your root (and low on space) like this:

`df -h`

It is most likely that your main root drive will be reported as `/dev/vda`. Assuming this is the case, you can try using `resize2fs` to resize the filesystem and make use of the extra space, like this:

`sudo resize2fs /dev/vda`

Make sure you use your actual drive name if it's something different to `vda`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Kurankat. [Here is the output of `df -h`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NMZ4.png). When I run the `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1` command as you have suggested, I receiver the following:

`resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
The file system is already 2620928 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!`

Is there anything else that I can try? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: No such file or directory while opening /dev/vda - any other solution ?